# Python Fetchone not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc, netezza

I am executing below code , but I'm not getting expected results for some of the records. DEFINITION column stores the SELECT statement of the view 'SAMPLE'. It's working for some views but not every views. Does anyone have encountered similar issue?

```
query="SELECT DEFINITION FROM database1.._V_VIEW WHERE database='database1' and VIEWNAME='sample'"
cur.execute(query)
definition=cur.fetchone()
print (definition )


>     SQL output : SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1
>     Python output : ('Not a view', )
```

Comment: But this is `fetchone`...

Comment: Sorry my bad. it's fetchone() . have you ever come across this issue. The contents in Defintion column are SQL queries. Does the length of the query has any effects. Don't know why it's behaving like this for some views. For some views, I'm getting correct output

Comment: I think you are connecting to some other database than "database1" . Can you share the script.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the database you are connecting might not have access to the view. For example, if I run "`SELECT DEFINITION  FROM database1.._V_VIEW`" query connected to some other database say "database2" it could happen.

Comment: It worked :) I was trying to run the query connected to a different database.